# Flurry Analytics not showing any Analytics

Tags: java, android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I setup everything like it said to on there website, but nothing happens. I am getting no logs from Flurry even though I set `.withLogEnabled(true).withLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)` and nothing is showing up in the admin. I know it can take some time, but I have waited for four days now.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        new FlurryAgent.Builder()
                .withDataSaleOptOut(false)
                .withCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true)
                .withIncludeBackgroundSessionsInMetrics(true)
                .withPerformanceMetrics(FlurryPerformance.ALL)
                .withLogEnabled(true)
                .withLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
                .build(this, MY_KEY_HERE);


        FlurryConfig flurryConfig = FlurryConfig.getInstance();

        flurryConfig.fetchConfig();

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was where I was calling the `FlurryAgent.Builder()`. On the website it looked like you called it in a class that extends the `Application` class. Actually you are supposed to call it in your main activity class. How could I get that mixed up?

Comment: You are supposed to call FlurryAgent.Builder in your application class, you had it right the first time.

Comment: Your right looking back at it now, you are suppost to call FlurryAgent.Builder in your application class, but I'm still not sure why I couldn't get it to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, you do not log any Flurry events! You need to use `FlurryAgent.logEvent` to log Flurry events.

`withLogEnabled` and `withLogLevel` are for your Android console logging, not Flurry event logging.

FlurryConfig is for Flurry Remote Configuration. It will not log any Flurry events neither.

Comment: Do you have to log events to log a sessions? And I am not even getting any console  logs for flurry.